# nohup: failed to run command 'source': No such file or directory error while runnşng nohup?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, login

I am trying to keep running of a command after logout from ssh. I used the commands `nohup source a.sh > a.txt` and `screen source a.sh > a.txt`. But both gives

````
nohup: failed to run command 'source': No such file or directory```
error. In one question, it is said that use the absolute path of command but I couldn't find the exact location of source command. But I can use nohup directly with other commands such as cp. How can I solve this issue or are there better alternatives?
````

Comment: Why are you using `source` there? It means to execute the named script in the _same_ shell, but since you're starting an external command (`screen` or `nohup`) anyway...

Comment: What can I use instead of source

Comment: `source` is not an external command. It is a shell built-in, and nohup needs an external command to run. If `a.sh` is on your PATH list, is executable, and has a shebang, that by itself is the command, like `nohup a.sh`. That is the proper way to do it. Otherwise, `nohup bash a.sh` will run `a.sh` even if it is not executable, and will ignore any shebang. If `a.sh` is not in PATH, you will need to run it as `./a.sh` or add whatever full pathname it is on. Note that `nohup` does not mean anything useful unless you also run it in background.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "source?"  Just do this...

```
chmod 700 a.sh
nohup ./a.sh > a.txt &
```

In a.sh, be sure you've specified the shell it should use as it's interpreter. (ie. #!/bin/sh)